# Using a shunt cap to create a delay - good idea?

Tags: voltage, ac, decoupling-capacitor, phase

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj10Ch.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

C1 is a decoupling capacitor. If the input of U1 is experiencing undesired phase shift, can a decoupling capacitor correct the issue?

credits to @Placeholder for rephrasing the question

Comment: Where's the decoupling cap?  On the power supply to ground?

Comment: Be careful of your terminology. A *coupling* capacitor is used to transfer a signal from one stage of a circuit to another, while blocking DC. A *decoupling* capacitor is used to reduce the impedance of a power supply bus, partcularly at higher frequencies. Any phase shift is related to how the impedance of the capacitor interacts with other impedances in the surrounding circuit.

Comment: With gross changes to the question, I don't know what to believe anymore.

Comment: Due to the edit, no one seems to know what it is about..

Comment: I am afraid, the new edition of the question is as strange as it was before.

Comment: So the Vdd line is a square wave?

Comment: This new version of the question makes even less sense. You now specifically say you are asking about a decoupling capacitor (reduces high frequency ripples on the power input of a chip), but your diagram shows neither a decoupling capacitor nor a coupling capacitor. You are creating confusion by trying to use words you don't understand. Step back and ask what you really want to know, and use plain English and diagrams. Avoid words you don't understand. Don't try to pretend to know more than you do. It won't make you look smarter, in fact exactly the opposite as this fiasco demonstrates.

Comment: Mea culpa, since I helped you get into this mess, I need to help you get out. That Capacitor is a shunt or parallel capacitor it is not a decoupling cap.  And yes, under certain conditions you can get a fixed delay from that.  Calling it a phase shift is not accurate.  The answer will be not so much of IF you can do this, but rather is it advised? So a new title of "Using a shunt cap to create a delay - good idea?" might work better.

Comment: fix up part II -  The delay created will depend very much on the output impedance of whatever is driving it, that information will need to be added.  It will also depend upon what the input thresholds of your chip are - let us know what you are driving _into_.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop I think I've got the answer (I wasn't trying to act smart), the confusion may well explain that fact that"decoupling capacitor cannot cause phase shift". This weird statement was first suggested by a respected local consultant engineer. Even I was confused by the fact that: 1.) The decoupling cap will just short ground and the input line 2.) No decoupling cap should cause significant phase shift - it is not meant to be. Special thanks to Olin Lathrop for the explanation, and my apologies for my poor English.

Comment: BY the way guys, how do I mark this as "asnwer"?

Answer (score 4):

No.  The point of a decoupling capacitor is to reduce high frequency ripple on the power to the chip.  Making the power perfectly flat only helps, not hurts, and has nothing to do with any phase shift of any signal going thru the IC.

Comment: It's a coupling capacitor!

Comment: @Leon: Not originally. That was changed well after I wrote this answer.  See the edit history of the question.

Comment: How do you view the edit history? (I thought I'd made a mistake.)

Comment: @George: You click on where it says "edited 1 hour ago" (or whatever the time is since the last edit). I believe some minimum rep is required to see edits on other people's posts. Check the "priveledges" section in your user profile. That tells you what you can do at what rep levels.

Comment: Ahh Thanks Olin,  So this was edited by "one of us" so to speak.  What about if the OP made an edit can we see that too?  (Sorry for all the meta questions.)

Comment: @George: If you can see the edit history, then you can see all of it as far as I know. Placeholder's edit completely changed the question, and should not have been done without input from the OP about what he really meant. The result was to create confusion, so all we could do was to close the question without the OP clarifying what he was really asking.

Comment: Many thanks for the effort of editing my title, but I intended for it to be "Decoupling Capacitor", that's the crux of the matter.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop: the title was intended to be "DEcoupling".

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it will, of course.
However - this phase shift will be frequency dependent and is determined by the associated time constant. If the inverse of this time constant is sufficiently small if compared with the signal frequency (that means: The cut-off frequency of the C-R highpass is sufficiently small) there will be no remarkable phase shift. 
As a rule of thumb you can perhaps use a factor of 100 (signal-to-cutoff frequency).

EDIT: This answer applies to COUPLING capacitors only.

Comment: Many thanks, but the question was intended to be "Decoupling capacitor".